# nested node class operator overload < c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, operator-overloading, nodes

I'm trying to overload the < operator for my nested Node class inside my LinkedList class.
I have it setup like this:

```
LinkedList<T>::Node& LinkedList<T>::Node::operator<(const LinkedList<T>::Node& rhs){
    return rhs; 
}
```

But I just get the error
`1>c:\users\kevin\workspace\linkedlist\linkedlist.h(185): warning C4183: '<': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'`

I try to return 1 but that doesn't work either.

Comment: In the header, did you forget to put the return type?

Comment: even if it is just a code snippet: you are trying to return a const Node& as a Node&

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Node` is a dependent name, so you need to use `typename` to tell the compiler you are referring to a type.

```
template <typename T>
const typename LinkedList<T>::Node& 
LinkedList<T>::Node::operator<(const typename LinkedList<T>::Node& rhs)
```

Also, note that you have a `const` reference, but you were returning a non-const one. You should return a `const` reference, but in real code, it would be very confusing for `operator<` not to return a `bool`. This would make more sense:

```
template <typename T>
bool LinkedList<T>::Node::operator<(const typename LinkedList<T>::Node& rhs) const
```

Comment: should this be going inside the node class or inside the linkedlist class?

Comment: @kevorski This is a definition, it goes outside of both classes. The declaration goes inside if the `Node` class definition. You can also put the definition inside there, but you'd have to ge tthe syntax right.